# for Materialized View in Cassandra, is it possible the read query returns different rows between by java driver and by cql

Tags: view, cassandra, mv, materialized

We have Materialized view in Cassandra, i am running a read query to get data from MV, however i find the result is different by using java driver and using cql, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the query that you're running, like, if you do `select * from table`, then the order of data is not guaranteed between partitions (only inside the partition).  Also, data could be inconsistent between different replicas, so you may need to perform repair on given materialized view, or use consistency level like, `LOCAL_QUORUM`.